# How to debug a failing SELECT statement?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a simple explanation why this query doesn't work, and what is its alternative?

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_category = 'shirts'
    AND WHERE item_category = 'pants'
```

I have to keep the clause:

```
SELECT * FROM items
```

because I need all the data that is selected for later use.

Comment: You have an extra `WHERE`, but this will never return any results. `item_category` can never equal both `shirts` and `pants`.

Comment: @Chris maybe he has jumpsuits or onesies :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't include `WHERE` twice:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_category = 'shirts' OR item_category = 'pants'
```

You also don't want to specify "`AND`", because there won't be a point where both `item_category` will be `shirts` and `pants` at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

You have two `WHERE` keywords; the second is not necessary -- it generates an error.

However, you should simplify the query to use `IN`:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM items i
WHERE i.item_category IN ('shirts', 'pants');
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, that query isn't equivalent to the OP's faulty one using `AND`. (It's probably what the OP _wants_, though.)

Comment: Forgot about the `IN()` clause. Nice alternative +upboat